# Write public file in controller; remote access hangs until action completes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-io, controller, actioncontroller

When implementing a controller action such as the following:

```
def create_file
    File.open('public/test.txt', "w+") do |f|
        f.write('test')
    end
    sleep(60)
    head :no_content
end
```

The file *domain*/test.txt will be accessible after the action completes; however, any attempts to access this URL before the action returns (such as during the sleep() call) seem to hang until it is finished.

I have use cases where I'd like to create publicly-accessible files based on user input, call a third-party API that requires passing a URL to such a file (no option to send the data iself in this case), then remove the file before the action is done.  Unfortunately, this seems to be impossible thanks to the file not actually be accessible until the action is finished.

Is there some way around this in Rails, some type of flush call or route refresh or handle closer?  I'm not sure why it's even hanging in this case.  Or am I going to have to use separate actions to create and process the file (assuming I don't want to store it on a static, non-Rails site on the same server)?

Comment: Which server are you using?

Comment: For web access?  I've actually only tested it with Thin in dev mode; production is using Apache+Passenger but haven't deployed it to there as it's not working...

Comment: The reason I ask, is it seems like you're running out of threads, is all. If you just have a single threaded server, any long operation will tie up the thread, no?

Comment: Hmm.. I think you're right.  For some reason I was under the impression that Thin could handle concurrent requests; it appears it can't by default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the problem was, as comments indicate, caused by only having one thread available to serve requests in development mode.  Solution was to add config.threadsafe! to config\environments\development.rb and to launch thin with the --threaded option.